# How can I enable or view Change Log in Mantis?

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis

I have installed Mantis bug tracker successfully and also uploaded some defects successfully.
But issue is that I am not able to view any change log activity or Road Map whenever I click on this option as an Administrator. Any dependency with this options or any need to change in configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set target versions or fix versions to your issues to benefit from the roadmap and changelog features.